# SQLite Android query returns no results with where

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an issue where when I execute my query with a WHERE clause it returns no results but if I leave the WHERE as null it will execute through all of my records and find the match. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my query?

in my code lets say that contactURI is equal to "content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/953i7d73a639091bc5b6/164" and contactUriId is equal to "164"

```
                // Put data in the contactURI
                contactURI = data.getData();

                // get the contact id from the URI
                contactUriId = contactURI.getLastPathSegment();

                //TEST TODO Fix URI Issue
                String [] PROJECTION = new String [] {  Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.LOOKUP_KEY };

                Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
                        + Data.MIMETYPE + "='*'",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contactUriId) }, null);

                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, contactUriId+"-164-");
                for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                     Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "lookupKey for contact: " + cursor.getString(1) + " is: -" + cursor.getString(0) + "-");
                     if(cursor.getString(0).equals("164")){
                         Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "WE HAVE A MATCH");
                     }
                }
```

This is my log...

```
05-14 19:08:40.764: D/OpenGLRenderer(21559): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-14 19:08:46.944: E/MyDebug(22269): 164-164-
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this:

```
Data.MIMETYPE + "='*'"
```

That is searching for `MIMETYPE`s literally named `*`. If you want to select all `MIMETYPE`s, don't do anything. A query returns all of these rows by default.

**Also,** this loop seems to execute, but it is not quite right:

```
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
```

Since `cursor` **has not** been move from index -1. This will safely start at the beginning and iterate until the last row:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

If you **have** moved `cursor` and want to start from the beginning again you can use:

```
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); ) {
```

**Detailed Explanation Why:** `cursor.isAfterLast()` does not move the cursor, it simply checks if the cursor is still referring to valid data. `cursor.moveToNext()` moves the cursor to the next row **and** returns `true` if the cursor is still in bounds. (In other words if `cursor.isAfterLast()` is `true` then `cursor.moveToNext()` returns `false`.)

Comment: Brilliant! That fixed my problem! Thank you so much Sam! I would vote up but I don't have enough rep.